# Python 3.11 + Mypy generic type hinting that can accept both types and type definitions

Tags: python, mypy, python-typing, python-3.11

I'm trying to write an arg getter with generics that casts the result to the correct type based on a generic type input:

```
T = TypeVar("T")
R = TypeVar("R")
P = ParamSpec("P")
GenericCallable = Callable[P, R]

def get_arg(
    name_or_pos: str | int,  # 0-based index
    typ: type[T],
    args: tuple[Any, ...] = (),
    kwargs: dict[str, Any] = {},
    fallback: T | None = None,
    throw: bool = False,
) -> T:
    found: Any = None
    if isinstance(name_or_pos, str):
        name = name_or_pos
        found = kwargs.get(name, None)
        if found is None:
            if throw:
                raise RuntimeError(
                    f"Could not find keyword argument '{name}' of type '{typ!r}' in"
                    f" {kwargs!r}"
                )
            found = fallback
    elif isinstance(name_or_pos, int):
        pos = name_or_pos
        if pos >= len(args):
            if throw:
                raise RuntimeError(
                    f"Could not find argument at (0-based) pos={pos}, not enough"
                    f" arg(s) (only have {len(args)}: {', '.join(*args)}"
                )
            found = fallback  # type: ignore

        found = args[pos]  # type: ignore

    if found is None:
        found = fallback

    return cast(T, found)
```

Given the following test cases:

```
def test_get_arg_for_functions():
    def func1(a: str, b: str) -> str:
        return f"{a} {b}"

    def func2(a: str, b: str, c: str) -> str:
        return f"{a} {b} {c}"

    class Class1:
        def __init__(self, x: int, y: str) -> None:
            self.x = x
            self.y = y

    kwargs = {"func1": func1, "func2": func2, "class1": Class1(1, "a")}

    got_func1: Callable[..., str] = get_arg("func1", type(func1), kwargs=kwargs)
    assert got_func1("a", "b") == "a b"

    got_class1_instance = get_arg("class1", Class1, kwargs=kwargs)
    assert got_class1_instance.x == 1
    assert got_class1_instance.y == "a"

    Func1Type = GenericCallable[[str, str], str]
    got_func1_from_type = get_arg("func1", Func1Type, kwargs=kwargs)
                          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    
    assert got_func1_from_type("a", "b") == "a b"
```

Mypy complains with the following, for `got_func1_from_type`:

> `Argument 2 to "get_arg" has incompatible type "<typing special form>"; expected "type[Never]"`

This (I believe) is because it is expecting `type[T]` and returning `T`, but here I'm passing a type definition.

So I tried instead with `type: T` and return `T` (or, to avoid confusion, let's call it `D`:

```
def get_arg(
    ...
    typ: D,
    ...
) -> D:
    ...
```

Now, Mypy is fine with me passing in the type definition to the generic `typ`:

```
Func1Type = GenericCallable[[str, str], str]
    got_func1_from_type = get_arg_def("func1", Func1Type, kwargs=kwargs)
    assert got_func1_from_type("a", "b") == "a b"
           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

but `got_func1_from_type` isn't callable because it's `type[(str, str) -> str]` and Mypy complains with:

> `Cannot instantiate type "GenericCallable[(str, str), str]"`

This makes sense, but I don't know what to do about it. I tried doing clever things like:

```
D = TypeVar("D", bound=type)
# or
D = TypeVar("D", bound=AnyType)
# or
D = TypeVar("D", bound=type[AnyType])
```

...but these are all binding the type definition to `type[TypeDef]` instead of `actual instance of type D`.

Is there a way I can either cast, or declare that it's returning the actual instance of the correct type, while allowing it to work for all of these use-cases?

```
P = ParamSpec("P")
R = TypeVar("R")
GenericCallable = Callable[P, R]

a_str = get_arg("a", str, kwargs=kwargs) # a_str: str

FuncType = GenericCallable[..., str]
a_func = get_arg("func", FuncType, kwargs=kwargs) # a_func: FuncType

an_instance = get_arg("class", MyClass, kwargs=kwargs) # an_instance: MyClass
```

(P.S., I tried a bunch of fancy stuff with `@overload` but couldn't get it to play any nicer than unions)

Comment: In the 2nd code block, how is `GenericCallable` defined?

Comment: Whoops, missed that - added @Mark

Answer (score 1):

It looks like type checkers don't like this:

```py
import typing_extensions as t

F = t.TypeVar("F")

def get(Type: type[F], /) -> F: ...
```

```
>>> FuncType = t.Callable[[int, str], bytes]
>>> get(FuncType)  # mypy: Argument 1 to "get" has incompatible type "<typing special form>"; expected "type[Never]"  [arg-type]
```

They're also inconsistent as to whether they accept a callback `typing.Protocol` as opposed to a `collections.abc.Callable`. You can see some experimentation in the type-checker playgrounds:

- [mypy Playground](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.12&gist=dcf971a6bf3173d928be7b4162e3fae1)
- [Pyright Playground](https://pyright-play.net/?strict=true&code=JYWwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYA7A5gfQKYA8baoDOwExcAhkQgLABQ9AYnALwIB0AKstgGoVQAFACJGwgDRwARhACuqACYsY7AMIUANhopSN2ANrsjklQEFUiALoBKegAVWHOwIogAymGwBjEXeG26ACVHFW5PfiFhQIk4LwgANwFgClQYFk4oWWwAxnkvMOwQtU1tXQN9NBhJIhgoS0kpRAIiS3p6L20ianUtOygIGAhBFT6BiDiNfTtJQJsALno4JbgFbAAzOExMLxKtwSJsDTXJAHpJACoBdCI5uDt2K6IL84BrAHdH2-v3x%2Bs4AFoAHxwQK3IzsNp0DpUai5VBeUaDYbsRHjCAaawLOjLFbrTbbXaYfaHY6UKDoACMt0qkiuACZbjUoKc-kDpE1sDc4ODIasNuhsDBBAVbkhPPpGPU4CdWcDGGCjJCAMQA-5qyFQbDxbCaTBi7CCAVCuH5HjWAKa7W6-WGwXInqlPT6Cqpaq1KWNZo2C1anUaPU8W3GvKo830S1%2BgOeIOCB2o500uBMj0clphhhQzrUADihGwUGAXgdOj0yNzqHzhamM3mi2WfPxOy0ewOR1OF0%2Bdwe5KecHOrw%2BPa%2B7B%2BPdlIIVEIzEetgaNgnLlaLJRL5UTyYaqe9ytVaqAA)

I think Pyright's implementation is more correct, if you read [PEP 484 - The type of class objects](https://peps.python.org/pep-0484/#the-type-of-class-objects) to the letter:

> Sometimes you want to talk about class objects, in particular class objects that inherit from a given class. This can be spelled as `Type[C]` where `C` is a class.

`FuncType` in `FuncType = t.Callable[[int, str], bytes]` is not a class, therefore it isn't compatible with `type[F]`. However, a `typing.Protocol` subclass is indeed a class, and therefore should be assignable to `type[F]`.

I don't really agree that rejecting the typing construct `collections.abc.Callable` in places of `type[F]` is *useful*, especially in this situation - but that's another story.

---

A workaround (also given in those playgrounds) is to lie a little and use a `typing.Generic`:

```
import typing_extensions as t

P = t.ParamSpec("P")
R = t.TypeVar("R", covariant=True)

class GenericCallable(t.Generic[P, R]):
    def __call__(self, /, *args: P.args, **kwargs: P.kwargs) -> R: ...
```

```
>>> Func1Type = GenericCallable[[str, str], str]
>>> reveal_type(get_arg("func1", Func1Type, kwargs=kwargs))  # mypy: Revealed type is "GenericCallable[[builtins.str, builtins.str], builtins.str]"
```

Answer (score 0):

Slightly radical idea (it might depend on your use case) - but any reason why kwargs can't just be a `TypedDict`? I've been wrestling with various code structures, but one thing I keep finding is that in each use of `get_arg` the type of the argument is known associated with each key. If the type is known, why can't we just use a more structured dict, and the type checker can tell you if an item is missing?

```py
from typing import Callable, TypedDict

def func1(a: str, b: str) -> str:
    return f"{a} {b}"

def func2(a: str, b: str, c: str) -> str:
    return f"{a} {b} {c}"

class Class1:
    def __init__(self, x: int, y: str) -> None:
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

class MyDictType(TypedDict):
    func1: Callable[[str,str], str]
    func2: Callable[[str,str, str], str]
    class1: Class1

def test_get_arg_for_functions():
    kwargs: MyDictType = {"func1": func1, "func2": func2, "class1": Class1(1, "a")}

    got_func1 = kwargs["func1"]
    assert got_func1("a", "b") == "a b"

    got_class1_instance = kwargs["class1"]
    assert got_class1_instance.x == 1
    assert got_class1_instance.y == "a"

    got_func1_from_type = kwargs["func1"]
    
    assert got_func1_from_type("a", "b") == "a b"
```

Appreciate this is little off-topic, but thought it might still be useful to you